# Implicit Verbs from Method name

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, http-verbs

If I create a webApi `controller`, and populate it with methods prefixed with http verbs, the Api is able to correctly imply what verb should be used on that controller.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "Called Get Method";
    }

    public string PostData()
    {
        return "Called Post Method";
    }

    public string PutData()
    {
        return "Called Put Method";
    }
}
```

If I replace the `Post` with `Update`, the Post method continues to work implicitly.

```
public string UpdateData()
{
    return "Called Updated Method";
}
```

Is there a list of the possible prefixes on a method and what verb they map to? Additionally, is it possible to define custom prefixes? For instance, if I wanted to always map a method starting with "Search" to a `Post`, can I define this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit Verbs are a function of the built in routing, and cannot appear to be manually extended.

This [Asp.Net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) details the specific rules around the implicit routing.

> HTTP Methods. The framework only chooses actions that match the HTTP method of the request, determined as follows:
>
> 1. You can specify the HTTP method with an attribute: AcceptVerbs, HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPatch, HttpPost, or HttpPut.
> 2. **Otherwise, if the name of the controller method starts with "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then by convention the action supports that HTTP method.**
> 3. If none of the above, the method supports POST.

The reason why the `UpdateData` method appears to work, is because any method not implicitly determined is automatically a `Post`

Comment: I was trying to figure out how the template AccountController was determining GET vs. POST. Extremely helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you put your `Routing` like the following :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Consider the `routeTemplate`.You'll now be able to call the `action`s on the `controller` by name,and no `prefix` issue should exist. This approach is very helpful if you have multiple actions on your `controller` with similar `HTTP Verbs`(multiple `GET` or `POST` say).